# Concrete class implements an interface which knows the concrete class that implement it

Tags: java

I have tried something, but I'm not sure why it seems to work.

I have an interface and then I have a concrete class.

The interface has a method that uses the concrete class, and that concrete class implements the interface.

Why is this working, if I call the implemented method??

```
public interface Interface {

    public void greeting(ConcreteClass concreteClass);
}

public class ConcreteClass implements Interface {

    public void greeting(ConcreteClass concreteClass) {

        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }

}

public static void main (String[] args) {

    ConcreteClass classObject = new ConcreteClass();
    test.Interface interfaceObject = classObject;

    interfaceObject.greeting(classObject);

}
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to fail?

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz: I think the OP's surprise is understandable; it's a bit surprising that Java allows two classes to be defined in terms of each other (with some restrictions). Still, it's a bit hard to answer . . . the answer to "why does it work?" is simply that there's nothing forbidding it.

Comment: It seems a bit strange and tricky the bidirectional knowledge from each entity and also because the relationship between them.

Answer (score 4):

This is precisely what `polymorphism` is.

```
ConcreteClass classObject = new ConcreteClass();
test.Interface interfaceObject = classObject;
interfaceObject.greeting(classObject);
```

Above code is same as

```
test.Interface interfaceObject = ConcreteClass();
interfaceObject.greeting(classObject);
```

Split the code into two parts - compile time and runtime.

At compile time Java compiler sees reference object `interfaceObject` on which the methods `greeting()` is called has corresponding method declaration. So it does not complaint.

Now at runtime JVM will know the object is infact an instance of `ConcreteClass` so will invoke the corresponding method (Given that `ConcreteClass` correctly implements `Interface` by providing concrete implementation of `greeting()` method).

Also there is no restriction on using method argument whose reference type is same as that of the class or interface to which the method belongs.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the classObject reference to the interfaceObject and calling the greeting method.
Interface is nothing but the super class without implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is perfectly acceptable it is usual nowadays to attempt as much separation as possible between your classes. Consider a module making use of your `Interface` would have to also import `ConcreteClass`.

The natural method to separate these is to use generics.

```
public interface Interface<T extends Interface> {

    public void greeting(T i);
}

public class ConcreteClass implements Interface<ConcreteClass> {

    public void greeting(ConcreteClass concreteClass) {

        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }

}
```